# Unit testing Client/Server App in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am currently developing Client/Server app based on **TCP protocol** in C/C++ and want to perform unit tests of both client and server side. 
I am using unix sockets for development.
Are there any MOCK libs or something similar to be used in testing or do I have to make wrappers in order to perform tests? Do these tests have to be **local** or they can be performed on **network**?

Comment: Unit tests must by definition be executed in isolation, so there's no running them over an actual network.

Comment: Your question would probably be better suited to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: unit testing implies local. on a network would be integration testing. However, it can be useful to build a mock server and run it locally.

Comment: Google Test supports both testing and mocking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least a few test frameworks you can use. For example [Google test](https://github.com/google/googletest)
which can include Google mock.
There are a variety of different tests you can develop for your application.

For unit tests, you must not use the network. The idea is to test only the logic.

But there are other tests that can be made which will use the network.
These tests are called system tests because they test the whole system.